# Spark SQL - Sum multiple columns in single query JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have over 50 columns for which i want to calculate sum using spark SQL. I don't want to manually write each column name. How can I do it programmatically

Comment: can you share example data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
val addNums = df.columns.map(case (c) => df(c))
                .reduce(_ + _)

val sumDF =  df.select(expr(addNums).as("SumOfFifty"))
```